# How to fix duplicate key error java 8 @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, postgresql, java-8

I have a ManyToMany relationship in java 8, that consists of array of id's on each side, user and track system. I have a linking table in the database that has a pkey on each column userId, trackSystemId. The primary key is a composite key of each id. Everything works fine when the user is first created but whenever I try and update the relationship, if a combination of userID and trackSystemId already exists I get a duplicate pkey error. What is the best way to fix this? Here is my code.

TrackSystem.java

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = 
     "allowedTrackSystems")
    private Set<DAOUserRecord> allowedUsers;
```

User.java

```
      @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinTable(
        name = "user_track_systems",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "track_system_id")
       )
      private Set<DAOTrackSystem> allowedTrackSystems;
```

Comment: You can try to load data before saving it so entity is in attached state. So JPA gets that you are about to update and not insert. Also you can set CasteTypes to inerst/delete/merge/... which is NONE on default.

Comment: awesome thank you, gonna try this now.

Comment: so would loading the owner side of the relationship, the user in this case, and calling clear work? And then save again

DAOUserRecord record = userRepository.findOne(newUser.getId());
record.getAllowedTrackSystems.clear();

Comment: It depends on your business usecase where the new relation is owned by. You can also make it bi-directional - just make it suite your usecases and dont mix it up just because it is complex ATM.